# Not able to understand a paragraph in John Conway's Complex analysis book.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

On page 97 under the heading "Counting zeroes; the open mapping theorem" there is a second paragraph which goes like this:

> In section 3 it was shown that if an analytic function $f$ had a zero
>   at $z=a$ we could write $f(z)=(z-a)^mg(z)$ where $g$ is analytic and
>   $g(a)\neq0$. Suppose $G$ is a region and let $f$ be analytic in $G$
>   with zeroes at $a_1,...,a_m$(where some of the $a_k$ may be repeated
>   according to the multiplicty of the zero.) So we can write
>   $f(z)=(z-a_1)(z-a_2)...(z-a_m)g(z)$ where $g$ is analytic on $G$ and
>   $g(z)\neq0$ for any $z$ in $G$.

Here since $a_k$'s are repeated according to their multiplicity, then why not $f(z)=(z-a_1)^{n_1}(z-a_2)^{n_2}...(z-a_m)^{n_m}g(z)$. where $g$ is analytic with $g(z)\neq0$ for any $z$ in $G$ and $n_1,n_2,...n_m$ are respective multiplicities?

Comment: Well,it is not said that all $a_i $ are distinct.

Comment: oh that means $a_i$ can be equal to $a_j$ in his equation.

Comment: I'm getting confused here.

Comment: yes it can be,then why are you confused?

Comment: If $a_i$ was equal to $a_j$, then why didn't he simply put powers as multiplicities? I'm confused because zeroes are seeming distinct to me.

Comment: Then you first need to define multiplicity of each root.It's just to make the notation simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no effective difference. It's just less clutter in the expression.

Comment: It's also more intuitive for most applications.